# Creating a Chrome app that just goes to a website/shortcut

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

There is a site we use that is also a webapp that will work offline as well as online once you open the first time.  We currently manually create a desktop shortcut in the chrome browser by bringing up the site, then clicking on the browser menu, go to More Tools, then Create Shortcut.  We also check the box for "Open as Window".  This then not only puts a shortcut that always opens in Chrome no matter what but also opens it a little cleaner it would appear.  When this is done an extension is created on the computer in the Google extensions folder.  I'd like to convert this to a Chrome app that can be deployed via group policy but even after going through the developer instructions I can't seem to get it to work.

I've taken the manifest.json that was created when I did it manually and added the missing parameters required of a chrome app, or at least from what I can tell.  I've even published the app in the chrome webstore.  But it just doesn't seem to work.

The original Manifest.json contains:

```
{"app": {
  "icon_color": "#C02331",
  "launch": {
     "web_url": "https://www.example.com/RunForm/Login"
  },
  "linked_icons": [ {
     "size": 16,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/favicon.ico"
  }, {
     "size": 32,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/favicon.ico"
  }, {
     "size": 48,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/runform/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"
  }, {
     "size": 64,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/runform/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"
  }, {
     "size": 76,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/runform/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"
  }, {
     "size": 96,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/runform/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png"
  }, {
     "size": 120,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/runform/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png"
  }, {
     "size": 128,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/runform/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"
  }, {
     "size": 152,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/runform/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"
  }, {
     "size": 256,
     "url": "https://www.example.com/Content/images/runform/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"
  } ]
},
"description": "",
"icons": {
  "120": "icons/120.png",
  "128": "icons/128.png",
  "152": "icons/152.png",
  "16": "icons/16.png",
  "256": "icons/256.png",
  "32": "icons/32.png",
  "48": "icons/48.png",
  "64": "icons/64.png",
  "76": "icons/76.png",
  "96": "icons/96.png"
},
"key": "sKDvXmTdpPytbue4P6yYy+6MRc+SMw5PutBMuCo/yLs=",
"name": "Run Form Login",
"version": "2019.5.28.54363"}
```

And then I added:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Run Form Login",
"description": "RunForm Login Page",
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
"permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "notifications"
]
```

I was expecting that this would then be installed via GPO as an extension like the one I did manually.  And then having a desktop shortcut to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe" --profile-directory=Default --app-id=[xx_TheAppIdOfTheExtension_xx] would just open then site in the window like it does when we make the link manually.  However it just opens Chrome. And it doesn't look like the extension is ending up in the extension folder either even though the information for forced installs is correct in chrome://policy

Comment: Also forgot to add that when I go to the webstore page for this link I attempted to create it only shows "Visit Webpage" instead "Add to Chrome" as on other apps.